# Remove unused imports from Angular module automatically

Tags: angular

I'm currently refactoring a large Angular application and removing some components from modules. It is easy and obvious to remove those components from the module.ts file. However, sometimes those components are using other imports that in turn won't be required to be imported anymore.
Example:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ZXingScannerModule} from '@zxing/ngx-scanner';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {PipesModule} from '../../../shared/pipes/pipe.module';
import {HeaderModule} from '../../../shared/header/header.module';
import {StandardService} from './state/standard.service';
import {StandardComponent} from './standard.component';
import {StandardCComponent} from './standard-c.component';
import {StandardBComponent} from './standard-b.component';
import {StandardDComponent} from './standard-d.component';
import {RefactoredComponent} from './standard.component';
import {StandardPlanComponent} from './standard-plan/standard-plan.component';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        StandardComponent,
        StandardCComponent,
        StandardBComponent,
        StandardDComponent,
        StandardPlanComponent,
        RefactoredComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        StandardService,
        StandardPlanService,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        ZXingScannerModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        PipesModule,
        HeaderModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MbscTimespanModule,
        MbscDatepickerModule,
        MatSelectModule,
    ],
})

export class MyAngularModule {
}
```

In the module above, suppose I deleted `RefactoredComponent` and removed from the module. I'm not sure which of the imports are being used only by `RefactoredComponent` and not by other components in the module. For example if `MatMenuModule` and `ZXingScannerModule` are being used only by `RefactoredComponent` and by no other module, is there a way to find this out without checking manually?

I would like to have unused imports removed automatically.

Comment: I've had the very same question many times. It seems that there's just no appropriate tooling available that could tell us which imports are necessary and which ones are unused. It should be possible to write an ESLint plugin / rule (with auto-fix) to do the feat! Anybody who wants to write one? Would be very appreciated :-)

Comment: Here's an issue in the Angular repo that's about the same thing: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41028